# Reclassify raster error 999999

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, reclassify, error-999999

I need to reclassify unsigned integer raster data.

I ran Calculate Statistics on the Raster, tried Reclassify, but keep getting  Error 999999: Error Executing Function. The description for the error is "This is a generic error for which the cause does not have a specific error ID."

I have 10 categories and need 2-10 reclassified to "0." Category 1 remains "1"

Here's my environments (I'm using ARCMAP 10.3.1)
[image]

What might the problem might be?